# UISegmentedControl iOS 13 change color of UIControlStateSelected and UIControlStateHighlighted together

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Trying to do something like:

```
[self setSelectedSegmentTintColor:tintColor];
[self setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: tintColor}
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But looks like I cannot do `forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted`. This is how my tabs look:

[image]

Which is ok. But when I press the selected item, the text color changes to white (tint):

[image]

Any way to configure the text color for selected & highlighted?

Comment: Try settings the "normal" state first, then the other states.